# If I drop all my tables and then recreate them will Linq to SQL break?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Right now I have a bunch of random data in my tables.

I've noticed that I do need to add a column or two here and there in my tables, so I'm a big curious about this... If I were to drop all my tables and then recreate them, will Linq to SQL notice?

Also, if I drop all my tables and then recreate them with a few of my tables having an extra column or two, will Linq to SQL pick up those new columns or will I need to regenerate my Linq to SQL classes?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you recreate them with the same definition, schema, permissions, etc, Linq to SQL will likely not notice, BUT it would be best to re-generate afterward just to be sure.

If you add new columns, you will need to re-generate, or add those manually. (It's easier to re-generate.)

Comment: So, it won't pick up the new fields automatically and if I make everything the same as before it will basically be like nothing happened?

That's what I was thinking would happen, so thanks for the help David.